# Angular 8 Directive for role based views

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular-directive

I am looking at this example for displaying components based on the role of a user:
https://blog.strongbrew.io/display-a-component-based-on-role/

My code won't compile because of missing arguments in my constructor inside `has-role.directive.spec.ts`. From `has-role.directive.ts` it takes 3 arguments: ViewContainerRef and TemplateRef from angular core, and a service for getting user roles.

`has-role.directive.ts`

```
    constructor(
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService)
```

But inside the example tutorial its used like this:
`has-role.directive.spec.ts`

```
 describe('HasRoleDirective', () => {
  it('should create an instance', () => {
    const directive = new HasRoleDirective();
    expect(directive).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

How can this in the example work, but for me it complains about missing arguments?
[image: From Visual Studio]

---

### UPDATE:

As Michał suggested i created classes to add to the constructor:

```
class TestViewContainerRef extends ViewContainerRef {
    element: ElementRef<any>;
    injector: Injector;
    parentInjector: Injector;
    clear(): void {
        throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
    }
    get(index: number): ViewRef {
        throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
    }
    length: number;
    createEmbeddedView<C>(templateRef: TemplateRef<C>, context?: C, index?: number): EmbeddedViewRef<C> {
        throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
    }
    createComponent<C>(componentFactory: ComponentFactory<C>, index?: number, injector?: Injector, projectableNodes?: any[][], ngModule?: NgModuleRef<any>): ComponentRef<C> {
        throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
    }
    insert(viewRef: ViewRef, index?: number): ViewRef {
        throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
    }
    move(viewRef: ViewRef, currentIndex: number): ViewRef {
        throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
    }
    indexOf(viewRef: ViewRef): number {
        throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
    }
    remove(index?: number): void {
        throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
    }
    detach(index?: number): ViewRef {
        throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
    }
}

let viewContainerRefMock = {
  viewContainerRef: TestViewContainerRef
};

describe('HasRoleDirective', () => {
  it('should create an instance', () => {
    const directive = new HasRoleDirective(viewContainerRefMock, templateRefMock, authenticationServiceMock);
    expect(directive).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Now it complains about my class:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, obviously you are missing some arguments as the error message describes. When using the directive in your application, angular creates those 3 dependencies and injects them into your directive.

In your example, you are creating an instance of your directive inside a test. Angular can't inject those dependencies because there is no Angular, it is a test. Since Angular is not providing them, you should provide them manually. This is explained [here](https://angular.io/guide/testing-services#services-with-dependencies).

The reason the blog you are referring to does not need them is that that blog does not unit test it.

Comment: Thanks, going to read this. Might be a good idea to read more at angular's docs i guess.

Answer (score 1):

just create mock classes for constructor parameters, that extend abstractions for your need. for ex. in `has-role.directive.spec.ts` create

```
class TestViewContainerRef extends ViewContainerRef { }
class TestTemplateRef extends TemplateRef<eny> { }
class TestAuthenticationService extends AuthenticationService { }
```

then implement all needed methods from interfaces. they can have body like `throw new Error("Method not implemented.");` - no matter, you will not be using it in such test. And just create object for each and put into `HasRoleDirective` constructor.

Comment: How could i implement these methods through interfaces? I seem to not get it right. The TemplateRef and AuthenticationService was working out of the box but "class TestViewContainerRef extends ViewContainerRef { }" just complains.

Comment: And how can he in the example not need to do this but i have too?